# How to prefix all controller paths but not management endpoints?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application with a lot of controllers, and I want to run the service on a sub-path of an existing domain. So I've figured it would be nicer to have this configurable than to hardcode the path into all the request mappings.

I've considered all the approaches mentioned here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-controllers-add-prefix, but they either also change the prefix of the actuator endpoints or are not globally enforced, so I'd prefer a different approach.

I want the actuator endpoints on `/_system/` (changed by `management.endpoints.web.base-path=/_system`) and have only the `/prefix` as a load balancer target, so the management endpoints won't ever be reachable from the internet (in case I miss-configure the application and start leaking some sensitive info from the management endpoints).

I've also tried configuring `management.server.base-path=/`, but that seems to also be affected by the `server.servlet.context-path` and `spring.mvc.servlet.path` as the actuator seems to be registered "under" the main servlet dispatcher.

I was looking into registering a separate servlet dispatcher just for the actuator endpoints, but I've given up on researching it after some time because I feel like I'd have to override half of Spring Boot.

Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Configure actuator to [listen on a separate port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764869/different-ports-on-spring-actuator). The load balancer would not forward requests to the actuator port. so actuator is not reachable from the Internet.